# How do I link a sway page to another sway page

Tags: office-online

I recently checked out Microsoft Office Sway. However, I found 1 big annoyance: I could not link to a 'page', or slide. Is there any way to do this?
For example, in Google Slides, I could hit  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  + <kbd>K</kbd> and then select `Slide: Name` [`Name` for the name]. In PowerPoint, I could go to `insert > hyperlink > places in this document > slide titles > 1: title`. Is there anyway to emulate this with office sway?